# insert unique points with buffer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am currently using this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Source') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Source
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Target') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Target

CREATE TABLE #Source
(
    Point GEOGRAPHY
);
CREATE TABLE #Target
(
    Point GEOGRAPHY
);  

DECLARE @PointBufferDistanceInMeters FLOAT;
SET @PointBufferDistanceInMeters = 3;

INSERT #Source SELECT GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText(N'POINT(102.0 0.5)', 4326); 
INSERT #Source SELECT GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText(N'POINT(102.0 0.5)', 4326); 
INSERT #Source SELECT GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText(N'POINT(102.0 0.50009)', 4326); -- 10 meter-ish away

SELECT * FROM #Source

INSERT INTO #Target
SELECT 
    GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText(Wkt, 4326) 
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT Point.STAsText() AS Wkt
FROM    #Source AS S
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 42
                        FROM   #Target
                        WHERE  S.Point.STDistance(Point) < @PointBufferDistanceInMeters)
) X

SELECT Point.STAsText() FROM #Target
```

to insert 'unique' points (with a buffer of 3 meters) into a target table #Target. I tested this and it seems to work fine. The results are a expected:

```
POINT (102 0.5)
POINT (102 0.50009)
```

Just curious, can this be improved in terms of efficiency or does anyone see anything amiss here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `INSERT` is filtering on the current state of `#Target` only. If `#Source` contains some non-identical points closer than `@PointBufferDistanceInMeters` from one another they all would get inserted.

I am afraid the only bullet-proof way to handle `GEOGRAPHY` data at the moment is through RBAR which might not be all that inefficient by comparison with double conversion `Point.STAsText() AS Wkt` => `GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText(Wkt, 4326)`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this and possibly suggest a fix?

Comment: Assume you have another record in `#Source`: `INSERT #Source SELECT GEOGRAPHY::STPointFromText(N'POINT(102.0 0.500091)', 4326); -- 1 meter-ish away`. Which Point(s) should make it to the `#Tagret`?

Comment: I see - tahnks. Guess some kind of tie breaker involving rownumber would be useful here.

Comment: Yes, and on top of that tie breaker one Point from #Source might be too close to the #Target, and the other not. So, first you would have to filter by distance to #Target and then - fellow #Source. It would be much easier to scan #Source row-by-row calculating distances to #Target and insert suitable one-at-a-time. That way for each Point from #Source you would already have all previous Points consistently in #Target ready for uniform comparison.

Comment: I guess a loop rather than set based approach would be ok then.

Comment: How accurate should this `@PointBufferDistanceInMeters` comparison be? Would you consider splitting `Point`s into `.Lat` and `.Long`, `FLOOR`ing them to particular precision and then comparing. That way the condition would be within "square area around" rather then "particular radius", but it might be much faster and more straightforward.